# How can I count occurrences of values in a list of dicts?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have this list of dicts:

```
[{'Description': 'LARCENY'}, {'Description': 'LARCENY'}, {'Description': 'BURGLARY'}, {'Description': 'ROBBERY - STREET'}, {'Description': 'COMMON ASSAULT'}, {'Description': 'COMMON ASSAULT'}, {'Description': 'AUTO THEFT'}, {'Description': 'AUTO THEFT'}, {'Description': 'ROBBERY - STREET'}, {'Description': 'COMMON ASSAULT'}, {'Description': 'COMMON ASSAULT'}, {'Description': 'BURGLARY'}, {'Description': 'BURGLARY'}, {'Description': 'LARCENY'}, {'Description': 'ROBBERY - COMMERCIAL'}, {'Description': 'COMMON ASSAULT'}, {'Description': 'COMMON ASSAULT'}, {'Description': 'COMMON ASSAULT'}]
```

I need to make a function that iterates over those dictionaries and counts how many times each type of crime has occurred. The output should be a list of dicts like this:

```
[{'LARCENY' : 3}, {'BURGLARY' : 2}, {'ROBBERY - STREET' : 3}...
```

For each type of crime, I need to know how many times that crime as occurred.
This is what I have so far:

```
result = {}
for k in data:
   if 'Description' in k:
    result[k['Description']] = result.get(k['Description'], 0) + 1
```

But the output given gives me everything in the same dict, but I want them to be in a list of dicts, each crime with each dict.

Feel free to ask any question if you don't understand mine.

Comment: Why? A single dict with unique keys will be more useful than multiple single keyed dicts.

Comment: It looks like you're asking for a list of dictionaries that just have one element in them each.  How is that better than just a simple dictionary?

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: After I get the desired output I will need to separate the keys and the values into diferent lists, using [li['Description'] for li in result]

Comment: if you have a dict d you can separate the keys into individual dicts by: [{k: d[k]} for k in d.keys()]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the result you've got so far...

```
>>> result = {'LARCENY' : 3, 'BURGLARY' : 2, 'ROBBERY - STREET' : 3}
>>> result = [{k:v} for k,v in result.items()]
>>> result
[{'BURGLARY': 2}, {'LARCENY': 3}, {'ROBBERY - STREET': 3}]
```

Answer (score 6):

While your data structure doesn't make sense as noted above, you can solve this easily using the Counter class from collections.

```
from collections import Counter

crimes = [{'Description': 'LARCENY'}, {'Description': 'LARCENY'}, {'Description': 'BURGLARY'}, {'Description': 'ROBBERY - STREET'}, {'Description': 'COMMON ASSAULT'}, {'Description': 'COMMON ASSAULT'}, {'Description': 'AUTO THEFT'}, {'Description': 'AUTO THEFT'}, {'Description': 'ROBBERY - STREET'}, {'Description': 'COMMON ASSAULT'}, {'Description': 'COMMON ASSAULT'}, {'Description': 'BURGLARY'}, {'Description': 'BURGLARY'}, {'Description': 'LARCENY'}, {'Description': 'ROBBERY - COMMERCIAL'}, {'Description': 'COMMON ASSAULT'}, {'Description': 'COMMON ASSAULT'}, {'Description': 'COMMON ASSAULT'}]

c = Counter()
for item in crimes:
    c[item["Description"]] += 1

print(c)
```

This gives the output of:

```
Counter({'COMMON ASSAULT': 7, 'BURGLARY': 3, 'LARCENY': 3, 'AUTO THEFT': 2, 'ROBBERY - STREET': 2, 'ROBBERY - COMMERCIAL': 1})
```

I'd recommend looking at the Counter class whenever you want to count things.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you want to maintain the order of occurrence of the crimes as well.

So, use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead of normal dict.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> counter = OrderedDict()
>>> for item in data:
...     if 'Description' in item:
...         counter[item['Description']] = counter.get(item['Description'], 0) + 1
```

Now, just construct a new dictionary with each and every key, value pair out of the `counter`, like this

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint([{k: v} for k, v in counter.items()])
[{'LARCENY': 3},
 {'BURGLARY': 3},
 {'ROBBERY - STREET': 2},
 {'COMMON ASSAULT': 7},
 {'AUTO THEFT': 2},
 {'ROBBERY - COMMERCIAL': 1}]
```

---

From the comments,

> After I get the desired output I will need to separate the keys and the values into diferent lists,

**Then, don't create list of dictionaries.** Directly create two lists, with `keys` and `values`, from the `counter` itself, like this

```
>>> list(counter.keys())
['LARCENY', 'BURGLARY', 'ROBBERY - STREET', 'COMMON ASSAULT', 'AUTO THEFT', 'ROBBERY - COMMERCIAL']
>>> list(counter.values())
[3, 3, 2, 7, 2, 1]
```